# Compile Android App in Visual Studio - how to target lower API level

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, android-ndk

I have installed Visual Studio 2017 15.8.9 with:
Xamarin 4.11.0.779
Xamarin.Android SDK 9.0.0.19

And I have installed Android NDK: android-ndk-r10e
[image]
[image]
[image]

As you can see on the pictures, I can only target down to Android 4.4. I have google very much and tried install lower Android NDK, install lower API target in Android SDK Manager, but nothing happens, it is the same.

Is there someone who know how to change to lower Api target?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you really want to target lower, or just have a lower minimum API level?

Comment: KitKat/4.4 is the lowest Xamarin.Android "compile" target framework available, you can perform runtime (BuildVersionCodes) checks to determine which APIs to run based upon your device runtime version (minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion) which could be lower then your compile target.

Comment: Well, i maybe been lower minimum api level. My goal is to run this app on my old devices that runs between Android 2.1 to 2.3. I can not see settings for minimum api level. Just <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="21"/> in AndroidManifest.xml file. Is it just that settings?

Comment: @Alexander https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/android-api-levels?tabs=windows#minimum-android-version